# How can I bring my OnClickListener for my Multiselectorspinner to work?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Multiselectorspinner (with checkboxes on the side) and want to get a call when something is clicked on.
Now I implemented the OnClickListener, but it only opens once the app starts and isnt called afterwards.
here is my code:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  var spinner: MultiSelectionSpinner
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.mySpinner1) as MultiSelectionSpinner
    spinner.setItems(Busliste)
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            println("works")
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            println("listener works")
        }
    }
```

> The MultiselectorSpinner I am using has the following code:

```
package com.hdmc.smartristraveller;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;



/**
 * Created by Aneh Thakur on 5/7/2015.
 */
public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends AppCompatSpinner implements
    OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
String[] _items = null;
boolean[] mSelection = null;

ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;


public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);

    simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
}

public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
    if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
        mSelection[which] = isChecked;

        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection,this);

    builder.show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
            "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");
}

public void setItems(String[] items) {
    _items = items;
    mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
    Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
}

public void setItems(List<String> items) {
    _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
    mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
    Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
}

public void setSelection(String[] selection) {
    for (String cell : selection) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
            if (_items[j].equals(cell)) {
                mSelection[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setSelection(List<String> selection) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
    }
    for (String sel : selection) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
            if (_items[j].equals(sel)) {
                mSelection[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public void setSelection(int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
    }
    if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
        mSelection[index] = true;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                + " is out of bounds.");
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public void setSelection(int[] selectedIndicies) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
    }
    for (int index : selectedIndicies) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[index] = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                    + " is out of bounds.");
        }
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {
    List<String> selection = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            selection.add(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return selection;
}

public List<Integer> getSelectedIndicies() {
    List<Integer> selection = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            selection.add(i);
        }
    }
    return selection;
}

private String buildSelectedItemString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean foundOne = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            if (foundOne) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            foundOne = true;

            sb.append(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public String getSelectedItemsAsString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean foundOne = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            if (foundOne) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            foundOne = true;
            sb.append(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Multiselectorspinner` or the library you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I couldn't get it to work, but what I did instead was making a timer with a handler. that timer would open every 2 seconds and see if any box is checked and give me back the string for it.
here is the code snipplet

```
val handler_spinner=Handler()
handler_spinner.post(Timer_identify_spinnerchange);
private val Timer_identify_spinnerchange = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        handler_spinner.postDelayed(this,2000)
        if(spinner.selectedItemsAsString.....){do sth}
    }
}
```

Maybe it helps someone someday